# Migrate from msal angular to azure webapp authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm working on a web application deployed on an azure webapp authenticated with Azure AD.
It is mostly based on the angular template for ASP.Net Core. The backend hosts the frontend in a ClientApp directory.

For the authentication, the frontend works with the msal-angular plugin which on access redirects to the Azure AD authentication page. After login, the login page redirects back to the frontend, which catch the token, and makes all the calls to the backend with the token in the authorization bearer header.

The .Net Core backend is configured with :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));
```

Finally, to make all these works, I have in the Azure AD app registration one entry for the backend and another for the frontend.

This works well, but we want to move away from that to use the Authentication directly on the webapp.
This way we could secure even more the application which would not even be downloaded if the user is not authenticated.

How do I manage to do that ?

- Do I need to remove all authentication code from the backend and frontend ?
- Do I still need 2 entries in the app registration on azure AD or one is now enough ?

How will I know which user is connected ? Actually I use the IHttpContextAccessor to get the UPN Claim.

Thanks for the help